# How to echo success message on same page and only upload image type file

Tags: php

This code running well.I want   I am trying to solve this with only upload Image type like png JPEG. and if error or success message is shown on the same page. and one thing all mail is going in spam box . so please help regarding this .

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action=""> 
    <label>Your Profile Pic<input type="file" name="my_file" /></label>
    <label><input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" /></label>
</form>
<?php
if($_POST && isset($_FILES['my_file'])) {

    $from_email  = 'sanjay@.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts
    $recipient_email = 'sanjay@.com'; //recipient email (most cases it is your personal email)

    //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them, 
    //$sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["sender_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
   // $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["sender_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
   // $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get subject from HTML form
   //$message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //message

   /* //don't forget to validate empty fields 
   if(strlen($sender_name)<1) {
       die('Name is too short or empty!');
   } 
   */

   //Get uploaded file data
   $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
   $file_name        = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
   $file_size        = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
   $file_type        = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
   $file_error       = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

   if($file_error > 0) {
       die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
   }
   //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
   $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
   $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
   fclose($handle);
   $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

   $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
   //header
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
   // $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
   //$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

   //plain text 
   $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
   $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
   $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
   // $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

   //attachment
   $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
   $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
   $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
   $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
   $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
   $body .= $encoded_content; 

   $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
   if($sentMail) { 
       //output success or failure messages   
       die('Thank you for your email');
   } else {
       die('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.');  
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: i want show error message on same page , after uploading  file .

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
if(isset($_FILES['pic']))
    {
        $target_dir = "./uploads/"; // upload directory
        $pics = $_FILES['pic'];

        //print_r($pics);
        $target_file = $target_dir.$time.basename($pics["name"]); // destination path
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // get file extension
        // check uploaded file exists or not
        if(file_exists($pics["tmp_name"]))
        {
            $check = getimagesize($pics["tmp_name"]); // get the image size
            if(!$check)
            {
                $Error['pic'] = "File is not an image.";
                $picErr="File is not an image.";
            }
            else if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif")
            {
                $Error['pic'] = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                $picErr="Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            }
            else if(file_exists($target_file))
            {
                $Error['pic'] = "Profile pic already exists";
                $picErr="Profile pic already exists";
            }
            if(empty($Error['pic']))
            {
                if(!move_uploaded_file($pics["tmp_name"], $target_file))
                {
                    $Error['pic'] = "Profile pic not uploaded";
                    $picErr="Profile pic not uploaded";
                }
                else
                {
                    $pic = $time.$pics['name'];
                }
            }
        } // file exists if end
        else 
        {
            $Error['pic'] = "Please select a image";
            $picErr="Please select a image";
        }
    }
```